# reading select box jquery issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `1` to `n` select boxes (maybe 5 or more). I am trying to loop the select box using jQuery but I don't understand fully how to do this. Please check my select box. I need only selected values in jQuery. Can I store each value in an array and pass via AJAX also?

```
<select name="myselect[]">
    <option value='1'>first</option>
</select>

<select name="myselect[]">
    <option value='2'>second</option>
</select>

<select name="myselect[]">
    <option value='3'>third</option>
</select>

<select>
    ------
</select>
```

My code

```
   $('select[name=myselect]').each(function(){
       var val+= ($(this).val());
      });
```

Comment: Where is your javascript/jquery? This is just html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this :

```
var array = [];

$("select").each(function () {
    if($(this).val() != undefined && $(this).val() != "")
    {
        array.push($(this).val());
    }

});
```

This will store every selected value in the array. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: The name of your select is `myselect[]` not `myselect`. You have to escape the `[]`. You can use `$("select[name=myselect\\[\\]]").each(function(){`

Comment: Try this : $('select[name*="myselect"]')

Comment: @Mathieu Labrie Parent I tried that too,It doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('select[name*=myselect]').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
         console.log(val);
    });
```

Try above code this will 100% work

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do won't work with your current code. The select's value will default to the single option present inside of it. The first select's value will always be "first" no matter what the user does.

If you want only the selects that have a value, you could add an empty option forcing the user to select a value.

```
<select name="myselect[]">
    <option class='noValue'></option>
    <option id='2'>second</option>
</select>
```

Then you can do some conditional logic to only get the ones that have a value.